# Why does this syntax not work for declaring associative array

Tags: bash, array

Can i use a variable inside () syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A c
declare -A b
a="[a]=0 [b]=1 [c]=2 [d]=3"
b=($a) # or b=($(echo "$a"))
echo "***********${b[@]}*********"  #********************

c=([a]=0 [b]=1 [c]=2 [d]=3)
echo "---------${c[@]}----------"  #---------0 1 2 3----------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's currently not possible (to my knowledge) to be able to take strings and create associative arrays with them in Bash. Therefore you must "evaluate" them prior using the `eval` statement.

When I run your example I get the following using Bash version 4.1.7:

```
$ ./arr.bash 
./arr.bash: line 5: b: [a]=0: must use subscript when assigning associative array
./arr.bash: line 5: b: [b]=1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
./arr.bash: line 5: b: [c]=2: must use subscript when assigning associative array
./arr.bash: line 5: b: [d]=3: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Changing the line to this works:

```
eval "b=($a)" # or b=($(echo "$a"))
```

Re-running you now get the expected results:

```
$ ./arr.bash 
***********0 1 2 3*********
---------0 1 2 3----------
```

#### Explanation

I found this SO Q&A titled: [Bash: How to assign an associative array to another variable name (e.g. rename the variable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660010/bash-how-to-assign-an-associative-array-to-another-variable-name-e-g-rename-t), which illustrates a method to do this using `declare` but it goes to show how unreadable this method actually is, and should probably not be used.

```
# declare associative array
declare -A assoc_array=(["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value2")
# convert associative array to string
assoc_array_string=$(declare -p assoc_array)
# create new associative array from string
eval "declare -A new_assoc_array="${assoc_array_string#*=}
# show array definition
declare -p new_assoc_array
```

This method shows the `$assoc_array` being converted to a string and then converted back to an associative array, `$new_assoc_array`. But even this method can't escape the need to use `eval`.  This is a difficult code snippet to follow and goes to show why it really should be avoided.

Comment: Why `eval`? You can run `declare` with parameterized contents with no `eval` preceding.

Comment: `s='["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value2"'; declare -A assoc_array="($s)"; echo "Value of key1 is ${assoc_array[key1]}"` <- no `eval` needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks.  Simply surrounding the part to the right of the equals sign with double quotes worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
eval "b=($a)"
```

`eval` will evaluate its argument as a shell command after performing parameter expansion. Use with care, though. Make sure that `$a` is not set by user input as this may lead to all sorts of trouble.

Comment: This does not answer the question, why the given syntax does not work.